# Database Schema design of server running status log

Tags: postgresql, database-design, schema, amazon-ec2

I am working with 4 AWS EC2 instances (servers). Each Instance has `Instance ID` and `Instance Name`. `Instance ID` is unique. Each of them having multiple application servers, like on of them is running `PUMA` server and another one is running `NGINX` and so on. I want to store the running status of the instances and their application servers in a database.

Like, If `Instance A` is running or not, that I can get by continuously hitting into the exposed port and store it in the database. I am scanning it in each minute. There will be 3 columns I can think of right now,

Instance A :-

```
Instance ID    Running Status   Time

Instance A        Running        10:10:04
Instance A        Running        10:11:04
Instance A        Running        10:12:04
```

Next, I want to store the status if Application Servers within Instance A running or not. There will be 3 columns I can think of right now,

Let's say `PUMA` and `NGINX` are running in `Instance A`

Instance A :- (Here also I am scanning it in each minute)

```
Application Name   Running Status   Time

PUMA                  Running       12:10:20
NGINX                 Running       12:10:20
PUMA                  Running       12:11:20
NGINX                 Running       12:11:20
```

I am using Postgresql. What will be the recommended schema design here ? Should I create a table for each instance and how will I map the applications with that particular Instance ? If I take `Instance ID` as a primary key then duplicate values in that column are not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time without date and timezone is pretty useless.

```
CREATE TABLE logz (
  server_inet inet,
  server_name text,
  app_name    text,
  is_running  bool,
  ts          timestamp with time zone
);

CREATE INDEX ON logz(server_name,ts);
CREATE INDEX ON logz(server_inet,ts);
```

Then to find the status of the server for each app.

```
CREATE VIEW running_status_by_name
AS
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (server_name,app_name) server_name, server_inet, app_name, is_running, ts
  FROM logz
  ORDER BY server_name, app_name, ts DESC;

CREATE VIEW running_status_by_inet
AS
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (server_inet,app_name) server_inet, server_name, app_name, is_running, ts
  FROM logz
  ORDER BY server_inet, app_name, ts DESC;
```

You could also use a pkid and easily do a `CROSS JOIN LATERAL (OFFSET 0 LIMIT 1)`.